# Openfiler RAID 10 option not found

Tags: software-raid, openfiler

I'm building a NAS using Openfiler2.3 (from 32-bit ISO), first of all I want to experiment it on VM first before going out and buy the harddrives needed.

I created 5 virtual drives on VMware, sda is 2GB and the rest 1GB each (sdb to sde).

I left sda blank and want to setup a RAID 10 disk using sdb, sdc, sdd and sde, 4 RAID partitions are setup successfully, but when I try to create a RAID device the only option for RAID level is 1, 0, 5 and 6.

RAID 10 is not there!

Can someone let me know what have I missed, please?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

You should create two raid-1 arrays and then create a raid-0 on top of their respective md devices. Or vice versa if you prefer 0+1 instead of 1+0

Comment: how is that possible in Openfiler?

Comment: I don't have one in front of me right now, but try to create two raid-1 arrays, one on sdb+sdc and second on sdd+sde
this should create two raid arrays - md1 and md2 (or mda and mdb)
Then you should try and create a new raid-0 array using md1 and md2

Comment: That's not possible, thanks anyway.

I found the option after Openfiler is installed, it's on the web interface, so the lesson learned is that one has to install Openfiler first on a partition that isn't prepared for the RAID array, but then the issue is that what if the boot partition fail?

Comment: http://linux-sxs.org/hardware/raid_for_idiots.html

Comment: The option I found is in the Web UI but the "add array" button is greyed out.

Does that imply I have to create the RAID manually as suggested above?

Comment: I guess I'll have to install openfiler in a VM to answer this one :)

Comment: Thanks dyasny, I think this issue is due to the (lacking of) robustness of the Openfiler UI.  I did follow the raid_for_idiots you recommended.  I found the line "for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do mknod /dev/md$i b 9 $i; done" makes the difference as Openfiler cannot perform raid10 without users intervention.